# Как сделать круговой эффект при клике на кнопку на CSS?

Tags: css

Как делать эффект круга при клике на кнопку?
Возможно ли это сделать на чистом CSS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот пример используя JS https://codepen.io/moitorrijos/pen/gXVMYg

Comment: Данную анимацию нельзя сделать без использования JS, так как нужно определить координаты куда нажал пользователь

Answer (score 1):

Обычно для таких вещей подключается что-то вроде MUI, Vuetifyjs или что-то подходяще в конкретном проекте.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(button => {
  let container = document.createElement('div');
  container.className = "button-bubble-container";
  button.append(container);
  
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    let size = Math.max(e.target.clientWidth, e.target.clientHeight) * 2;
    
    let bubble = document.createElement('div');
    bubble.className="button-bubble";
    
    bubble.style.height = size + "px";
    bubble.style.width = size + "px";
    bubble.style.top = (e.offsetY - (size / 2)) + "px";
    bubble.style.left = (e.offsetX - (size / 2)) + "px";
  
    container.append(bubble);
    
    const removeBubble = () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", removeBubble);
      
      bubble.style.opacity=0;
      setTimeout(() => bubble.remove(), 300);
    };
    
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", removeBubble);
  });
});
```

```css
.button-bubble-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;

  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  inset: 0px;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.button-bubble {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;

  animation-name: button-bubble;
  animation-duration: 550ms;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.29, 0.17, 0, 1);
}

@keyframes button-bubble {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}



.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bf0702;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;

  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


.button.big {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  button
</div>

<div class="button big">
  bigger button
</div>
```